# When is the density matrix not diagonal?

Tags: functional-analysis, physics

The density matrix (density operator) in quantum mechanics is defined as
$$\hat{\rho} = \sum_{i} p_i |\psi_i\rangle \langle \psi_i|\, ,$$
where the $|\psi_i\rangle$ are a full orthonormal system and the $p_i$ are probabilities, so
$$p_i \geq 0, \quad \sum_i p_i =1 \, . $$

When is the density matrix not diagonal? If we express the matrix in the basis $|\psi_i\rangle$, shouldn't it be always diagonal?

Comment: That would appear to be the definition of diagonal.

Answer (score 0):

It loses diagonality when there are transitions (real values) or superpositions (imaginary values) between states. Such an example would be for Electromagnetically Induced Transparency (EIT) where the density matrix is actually Hermitian ($\rho=\rho^\dagger$, $\rho_{ii}\in[0,1]$, $\sum\rho_{ii}=1$, and $(\rho_{ij}=\rho_{ji}^*)\in\mathbb{C}$ for $i\neq j$)